# Html5 Canvas and laptop perf

Tags: html, canvas

I have some problem with my canvas developpment game.

my website is pretty laggy, particulary on chrome and safari for a new laptop.
and laggy for all borwsers,in my older laptop (2006)

Google developer tools show me that the cpu is not really use by my javascript developpment !
only 3% is used.
97% free to use

So I was wondering where do I have to look to solve this problem.
can the graphic card perf, Canvas animation ?
and if so how can I solve that ?

My canvas animation is not really big : 200px X 1000px, but it seems that when I reduce it ( 200px X 100px) the animation looks smoother ? 
when I display all my background images too...

So I'm confusing.
Can it be a graphic card minimum requirement for using some complex animation with canvas ?

I really don't know where to look.

thanks in advance

Comment: What are you doing with the canvas? That could bog up your video card.

Comment: a yoyo, rotate and going up and down.

Comment: It looks smoother since I disable GPU acceleration in the latest chrom Browser. So I'm deeply lost now

Comment: Do you have some kind of working example?